# Shared story map link requiring sign in?

Tags: arcgis-online, authentication, story-map

I finished a story map with my ArcGIS Online account and linked it on Facebook and was told by someone that they need to sign in.

Why's that?

Comment: I've shared the map and data. So, it's public. So, I'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: can you share the link with us? This might help in debugging

Comment: This link has you sign in: http://jared.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapTour/?appid=0a037774a71f4de5bcd0e6ce578ee3e8

Comment: But, the URL given in the builder mode does not require it: http://bit.ly/1qYxgYW

Comment: Not sure if you made any changes over the weekend - but I can visit either of those URLs without logging in. I'm not asked to log in at any point.